# How to access functions in packages in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have this code in `app.py` and it works fine:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    return 'Hello'
```

Now, I added a subdirectory `interface` under the directory where `app.py` resides. In this subdirectory I added two files:

`__init__.py` (empty), and 
`test2.py` with the following content:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test2', methods=['POST'])
def hello2():
    return 'Hello2'
```

If I try to access `/test2` I get a 404 not found error. How to make Flask aware of `test2` ?

Comment: Going a bit broader, it looks like you're trying to implement the "blueprint" model. This is the source code for the Stack Overflow community website for Python: https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site Is that kind of structure that you're looking to implement? Note how each page has its own set of `routes`, `models` and `forms`. The accompanying site is [here](https://sopython.com/)

Comment: [This is the simplest](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/10/11/refactoring-flask-blueprints/) example I found on how to separate Flask functions in multiple files using Blueprint

Comment: As others have stated, blueprints are way to go. But, to make that 'subdirectory' aware: just import that app (do not declare a new one!) instance from the root folder, and declare your route like you did.

Comment: yes, I imported the app when I followed the example above.